# Problem With Jquery Ajax chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Hi Im new to jquery, I've been having some problems with this ajax request in chrome. It works without sending errors but you have to click the radio buttons 2-3 times before chrome updates the #change div with the new data

```
$(':radio').change(function() {




    var size = $('#sizeselect :radio:checked').attr('name');
    var colour = $('input:radio[name=col]:checked').val();



     $('#change').html('<p><img src="ajax-loader-2.gif" width="220" height="19" /></p>');


    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url : 'php.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: 'size=' + size + '&colour=' + colour,
    success : function (data) {
    $("#change").hide().html(data).fadeIn(700);

    }

});         


                    });
```

anyone got any ideas?

---

still getting the fault I've checked the inspector and its not throwing any errors. below is a link to the problem

http://www.regionalartwork.co.uk/jquerytest/index.html

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `async: false` as this blocks all other JS execution during the request.

Comment: @Matt Ball: +1. It also removes the 'A' from 'AJAX'.

Comment: try sending data as per the Jquery examples data:{ post_size: size, post_color : colour}

Answer (score 0):

Check out that your request isn't taking too much time and that Chrome is not waiting for the server to answer. Use Chrome's Inspector, Network tab for that :

Ctrl + Shift + I on Windows
Cmd + Shift + I on Mac.

And why not use it for debugging your Js. From what you show us, it should work.

Comment: still getting the fault I've checked the inspector and its not throwing any errors. below is a link to the problem

http://www.regionalartwork.co.uk/jquerytest/index.html

Comment: I've just tried out the link, you gave. Everything works fine. I've got an area on the right displaying a loading bar and short after showing "color and size".